# Setting parameters in before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This is not so much a how-to question but is more of a why question. Consider the example below, where I am trying to set a default email in before save.

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_default_email

  def set_default_email
    email ||= 'info@'+ domain
  end
end
```

The above method unfortunately does not work. Instead if add a self like shown below, it works fine and the value gets passed on to the db.

```
  def set_default_email
    self.email ||= 'info@'+domain
  end
```

However, given that the default receiver in ruby is self (which is why it understands domain etc.), shouldn't self.email and email be the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Ruby assumes construction `variable = value` to be local variable assignment. That's why in setter method, you have to point receiver explicitly.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on the other answers a bit, if you break down `||=` you get

```
email = email || 'info@'+ domain
```

which is equivalent to

```
email = self.email || 'info@'+ domain
```

`self.email` is nil, so it will evaluate to

```
email = 'info@'+ domain
```

And that's set a local variable, but doesn't call the `email=` method.

This is one reason why it's good practice to ALWAYS use `self.` rather than rely on Ruby's default scoping.  It's also much more readable:  another coder scanning your code can easily see that when you do `self.email =` (or `self.email ||=` in your case) you're calling the setter method, rather than defining a local variable.

Comment: Thank you. I used to explicitly mention self everywhere for clarity until rubocop started complaining about it. Oh well!

Comment: <investigates...> rubocop is based on the ruby style guide which says "Avoid self where not required. (It is only required when calling a self write accessor.) [".   I think that the style guide is wrong here:  i can't think of any reason to not type `self.`.  There's no issue with making your code more efficient by having less characters, and there's definite readability benefits to using `self.`  If i'm outvoted by the ruby community then that's fine, i'm not going to change though :)

Answer (score 1):

if you don't use `self.` what you are doing is defining a local variable, instead of calling the setter